# c language 'order of memory allocation' and 'execution speed'

Tags: c, arrays, performance, memory-management

I'm making a program using c.

I have many arrays and size of each array is not so small.
(more than 10,000 elements in each array).

And, there are set of arrays that are accessed and computed together frequently.

For example,

```
a_1[index] = constant * a_2[index];
b_1[index] = constant * b_2[index];
```

a_1 is compute with a_2 and b_1 is computed with b_2.

Suppose that I have a~z_1 and a~z_2 arrays, in my case, 
 is there significant 'execution speed' difference between the following 2 different memory allocation ways.

1. allocating memory in order of a~z_1 followed by a~z_2
2. allocating a_1,a_2 followed by b_1,b_2, c_1,c_2 and others?

1.

```
MALLOC(a_1);
MALLOC(b_1);
...
MALLOC(z_1);
MALLOC(a_2);
...
MALLOC(z_2);
```

2.

```
MALLOC(a_1);
MALLOC(a_2);
MALLOC(b_1);
MALLOC(b_2);
...
MALLOC(z_1);
MALLOC(z_2);
```

I think allocating memory in second way will be faster because of hit rate.

Because arrays allocated in similar times will be in the similar address, those arrays will be uploaded in the cash or RAM at the same time, and therefore computer does not need to upload arrays in several times to compute one line of code.

For example, to compute

```
a_1[index] = constant * a_2[index];
```

, upload a_1 and a_2 at the same time not separately.

(Is it correct?)

However, for me, in terms of maintenance, allocating in first way is much easier.
I have AA_a~AA_z_1,AA_a~AA_z_2, BB_a~BB_z_1, CC_a~CC_z~1 and other arrays.
Because I can efficiently use MACRO in the following way to allocate memory.

Like,

```
#define MALLOC_GROUP(GROUP1,GROUP2)
    MALLOC(GROUP1##_a_##GROUP2);
    MALLOC(GROUP1##_b_##GROUP2);
    ...
    MALLOC(GROUP1##_z_##GROUP2)

void allocate(){
   MALLOC_GROUP(AA,1);
   MALLOC_GROUP(AA,2);
   MALLOC_GROUP(BB,2);
}
```

To sum, is allocating sets of arrays, computed together, at the similar time affects to the execution speed of the program?

Thank you.

Comment: "Because arrays allocated in similar times will be in the similar address [...]" sounds like a scary assumption. You don't know that to be true, it's not guaranteed by any standard. It might be true in practice, but I'd *really* expect allocation *size* to have to be the same too. Of course, for your case that might be implicitly true.

Comment: Why don't you try and find out which one is faster ? Probably you won't notice any difference.

Comment: It seems like your arrays are much larger than the cache-line size anyway, so it probably won't make much difference. You could profile it if you want to. Where the cache would make a difference is for accessing multi-dimensional arrays in a set of nested loops, where you'd gain speed by looping through the dimensions in the most optimal order.

Comment: Or just don't do multiple allocations at all;  if you arrays are all the same size, then just allocate a single chunk of memory large enough to hold all of them and use a bit of math to access.  How you layout the items can be varied to minimize the math involved;  interleaved or consecutive (or something else).

Comment: @unwind I also suspected my assumption. And that's why I uploaded this question.

Comment: @Michael Walz Actually, trying both things takes time, so I wondered maybe someone also was curious about this issue and know the answer. As Ian Abbott mentioned, many of my array size is larger than cache (mostly larger than L1 and L2 cache size but not L3). So, maybe it won't make big difference.

Comment: @Ian Abbott thank you for suggestion. I need to check later

Comment: @bbum It looks interesting. Although each array has different size, in some points, I can apply this . If it doesn't make readability worse so much, I need to decrease multiple allocations.

Comment: Pardon if it's a stupid question, but do you need the original values in your arrays `a~z_2` after you multiplied them by `constant`? I am trying to imagine an algorithm that needs them both...

Comment: @Vlad Feinstein That was a simple example. You may imagine this. To optimize parameter, calculate New_Para(a_1[i]) = Previous_Para(a_1[i]) + Step_size_constant * a_2[i] (error caused by this parameter (delta_para))